# Efficiency in if/ifelse logic

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to write the following, as the first group of URLs all have the same result. Thanks in advance.

```
    <?php 
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/feet-foxes/') !== false) {
    echo '';
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/aerial-immersion/') !== false) {
    echo '';
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/taste-paper-air/') !== false) {
    echo '';
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/dance-movement-therapy-group/') !== false) {
    echo '';
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/fencing-fun/') !== false) {
    echo '';
}
elseif ($ticketlink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Ticket-Link-1', true)) {
    echo '<div class="artist-buy-tickets-box"><a class="artist-buy-button" href="'.$ticketlink.'" title="Buy tickets" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>';
}
else { 
    echo '<h6>TICKETS ON SALE<br/>JUNE 15 2011</h6>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Basically this writes a ticket sales button. Some shows are selling their own tickets hence the empty string, others sell through an online vendor hence the link, and some have not started selling yet hence the date.

Comment: That's not the point. To my knowledge, `echo '';` does **nothing**.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to acheive, some pages need no link hence echo'';

Comment: No, you don't understand. If you want no link, you don't do anything at all. No echo. Remove it.

Comment: Oh I see, I had assumed that something was required, sorry, and thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I 'm quite sure what your criteria for efficiency are, but here's a nicer alternative. It requires PHP >= 5.3 for the anonymous function (it can be done in earlier versions, but using `create_function` is kind of a chore).

```
$urlPaths = array(
    '/fencing-fun/',
    '/dance-movement-therapy-group/',
    '/taste-paper-air/',
    '/aerial-immersion/',
    '/feet-foxes/',
);

if (!empty(array_filter($urlPaths, 
                        function($item) {
                            return stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $item) !== false;
                        }))
{
    echo '';
}
```

My apologies for the atrocious indenting -- I couldn't come up with anything substantially less ugly.

Comment: Nice solution, anonymous functions only work in PHP 5.3 though, right?

Comment: @phant0m: No, you can create anonymous functions since PHP 4 with [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php). It's just that the PHP 5.3 syntax is so much easier to work with.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant :) create_function has a horrible syntax really.

Comment: You should expand the code to accomodate for all the functionality in the OP's code, btw ;) - You also output an empty string, why?

Comment: @phant0m: I don't think copy/pasting the last two branches will add value to the answer. And it's the OP's affair why they echo an empty string, I just copied that over. :)

Answer (score 1):

The call to `stripos()` is very likely to be cheaper than the call to `get_post_meta()` so do those first. In order to (micro) optimize, let the five tests with same result be a single expression:

```
<?php 
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/feet-foxes/') !== false
        || stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/aerial-immersion/') !== false
        || stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/taste-paper-air/') !== false
        || stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/dance-movement-therapy-group/') !== false
        || stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/fencing-fun/') !== false) {
    echo '';
} elseif ($ticketlink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Ticket-Link-1', true)) {
    echo '<div class="artist-buy-tickets-box"><a class="artist-buy-button" href="'.$ticketlink.'" title="Buy tickets" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>';
} else { 
    echo '<h6>TICKETS ON SALE<br/>JUNE 15 2011</h6>';
}
?>
```

This eliminates the need for duplicated code (`echo '';`). You can sort the tests to let the most frequent URI be first in order to take advantage of [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (I suspect this to be strictly theoretical, though).

Answer (score 1):

```
$needles = array('/feet-foxes/', '/aerial-immersion/', 'etc');
$found = false;
foreach($needles as $needle){
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $needle) !== false){
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!$found){
    if ($ticketlink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Ticket-Link-1', true)) {
        echo '<div class="artist-buy-tickets-box"><a class="artist-buy-button"   href="'.$ticketlink.'" title="Buy tickets" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>';
    }
    else { 
        echo '<h6>TICKETS ON SALE<br/>JUNE 15 2011</h6>';
    }
}
```

Are you sure you want to assign something inside the if?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite as the following. This way it's a breeze to add more URLs to the group that have the same result.

```
$echo = null;

$paths = array(
    'feet-foxes',
    'aerial-immersion',
    'taste-paper-air',
    'dance-movement-therapy-group',
    'fencing-fun'
);

foreach ( $paths as $path ) {
    if ( stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'.$path.'/') !== false ) {
        $echo = '';
        break;
    }
}

if ( !is_null($echo) ) {
    echo '';
} else if ( $ticketlink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Ticket-Link-1', true) ) {
    echo '<div class="artist-buy-tickets-box"><a class="artist-buy-button" href="'.$ticketlink.'" title="Buy tickets" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>';
} else { 
    echo '<h6>TICKETS ON SALE<br/>JUNE 15 2011</h6>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!preg_match('#/(feet-foxes|aerial-immersion|taste-paper-air|dance-movement-therapy-group|fencing-fun)/#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    if ($ticketlink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Ticket-Link-1', true)) {
        echo '<div class="artist-buy-tickets-box"><a class="artist-buy-button" href="'.$ticketlink.'" title="Buy tickets" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>';
    }
    else { 
        echo '<h6>TICKETS ON SALE<br/>JUNE 15 2011</h6>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the same action is taken, just lump them all in to one condition. However, it looks like you're doing nothing, so the top section shouldn't be required?

```
<?php 
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/feet-foxes/') !== false || 
    stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/aerial-immersion/') !== false ||
    stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/taste-paper-air/') !== false ||
    stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/dance-movement-therapy-group/') !== false ||
    stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/fencing-fun/') !== false
    ) {
    // If you're actually doing nothing - this whole section isn't needed?
    echo '';
}
elseif ($ticketlink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Ticket-Link-1', true)) {
    echo '<div class="artist-buy-tickets-box"><a class="artist-buy-button" href="'.$ticketlink.'" title="Buy tickets" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>';
}
else { 
    echo '<h6>TICKETS ON SALE<br/>JUNE 15 2011</h6>';
}
?>
```

Comment: It's for a template shared between 20 - 30 pages selling tickets for shows, some artists sell their own tickets so don't need a link hence the echo''; of the remaining artists some have a link to a ticket, hence the link and some are not on sale yet hence the date.